# List files but exclude certain directories in Unix

Tags: linux, ls

I am attempting to list files in a folder with sub folders recursively, but trying to avoid going into one folder as they are duplicates.

This is the command I run but it doesn't do anything.

```
ls -lR /opt/elk/data/syslogs | grep -v .log. | grep --exclude-dir="cam" * > /tmp/logs.log
```

If there any changes I can make to this?

Thanks.

Comment: `man find`.  Options will change greatly depending on your platform/version of find, and `unix` is way too broad to determine what you have.

Comment: Hey, I am on RHEL 7.2

Comment: `RHEL` is linux, linux is gnu-linux, and gnu's not unix.  You should probably change the tag to `linux`.

Comment: Sorry about that -- updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options to different versions of `find` vary greatly, but you may try:

```
find /opt/elk/data/syslogs -name cam -prune -o -print
```

On RHEL, you probably have gnu find, and if you want file size and modification time, you might try:

```
find /opt/elk/data/syslogs -name cam -prune -o -printf "%p %s %t\n"
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. I am on rhel 7.2 and I was trying to use it with ls -l .. as I needed to get the file size and last updated date etc.

Comment: Instead of `-print`, use `-exec stat {} \;` or `-exec ls -l {} \;`.  There are better ways to get this information with `find`, but these are pretty generic and should work with most implementations.

Comment: hey, that seems to work, is it possible to output the file without full path? Also, I would like to apply a filter to the filelist itself. I am wondering How I can add that to the command. thanks